# How does matrix vector multiplication scale a norm of vector?

Tags: matrices, fast-fourier-transform

Given a square Vandermonde matrix

$\mathbf{V} =$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \ldots x_0^{n-1}\\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \ldots x_1^{n-1}\\
\vdots\\
1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & \ldots x_{n-1}^{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}

and an integer vector $\mathbf{a}$ of length $n$:

$\mathbf{a} = (a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})^T$,

we can compute a vector $\mathbf{a}' = \mathbf{V}\cdot \mathbf{a}$ via matrix-vector multiplication.

In this case, what is the relationship between $\max({\mathbf{a}})$ and $\max({\mathbf{a'}})$??

Comment: what do you mean by max($a$)?

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation. That is a maximum element in $\mathbf{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is equivalent to discussing the relation between the maximum value of a polynomial evaluated at $n-1$ points and the largest coefficient.

I don't think that there is any simple relation. For even $n$ (odd degree) or odd $n$ with a positive leading coefficient, the maximum is unbounded (asymptotic to $a_{n-1}(\max(\mathbf x))^{n-1}$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If the element of the matrix can be expressed by a known constant (such as the complex n-th root of unity used in FFT), isn't it possible to bound the largest coefficient of the polynomials evaluated at those points?

Comment: @mallea: do you mean "bounded by a known constant" ?

Comment: Exactly! Bounding the amount by something like $C \max (\mathbf{a}) $ where $C$ is some constant.

Comment: @mallea: what *amount* ??